# Can hot days damage your camera?

Tags: dslr, sensor, equipment-damage, heat, canon-600d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What will happen to a camera if it is taken to an environment beyond its operating temperature?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24415/what-will-happen-to-a-camera-if-it-is-taken-to-an-environment-beyond-its-operati)

I have a canon t3i and I am curious to know just how much heat they can handle. I've seen proof that they can handle short bursts of [direct fire](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1tTBncIsm8), but long-term heat is another matter. I live in Texas and it's not uncommon for +110F temps in the summer.

If I leave that camera in the trunk - will it be ruined? Will the sensor quality go down? I want to take my camera with me everywhere - but if there is no air-conditioned area to keep the camera in I am worried I'll ruin it and be left without a camera.

[According to Canon](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/slr_cameras/eos_rebel_t3i_18_55mm_is_ii_kit#Specifications), I should not be using the camera above 104F/40C - but what about the non-working range where I have it sitting somewhere?